# Tomcat: How to disable Tomcat home page

Tags: tomcat

I deployed my application in Tomcat and the application path is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

but I want to restrict my users to not see Tomcat home page i.e. if they enter:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

the home page shouldn't appear. What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

refer [How to Change Default Homepage in Tomcat](http://blog.watashii.com/2008/10/how-to-change-default-homepage-in-tomcat/)

EDIT:

link is broked so you can try following:

The easiest would be to have the Tomcat home page (TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp) perform a redirect to your start page.

Or, if you have just a single web app, you can move that to the ROOT web app.

Answer (score 11):

rename the ROOT app to another folder name (or delete it if you don't want to manage tomcat with the tomcat manager app)

Put the app you want to see at http://localhost:8080 in the ROOT folder

Comment: Thank you. Renaming the `ROOT` app to `ROOT-Closed` and `examples` to `examples-closed` in the `webapps` folder worked for me. You can rename it to any name you want.

Answer (score 5):

I think the author of the question asked specifically about disabling Tomcat home page, not redirecting it.
I found helpful tip on ibm website. I tried it and it worked for me.
Here are steps:

1. Go to Apache Tomcat conf directory
2. Edit the web.xml file content. Comment out following lines:

```
    <!--
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    -->
```

IBM reference web page: [Disabling the Apache Tomcat default home page on ...](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/disabling-apache-tomcat-default-home-page-openpages-reporting-server)

Answer (score 4):

Upload ROOT.war with some other content or alternatively try to remove the folder ROOT/ from webapps

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered that you can connect as manager when the application is in production and stop the welcoming page.
[image]

And if someone try to access again the welcoming page (http://localhost:8080), it will not work:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options to do this apparently. One very good reference that compiled those for me is:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat

This talks about Tomcat 5.5 primarily. But I see little reason why most of it should not work for higher versions of Tomcat namely 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

rename the index file inside root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might think changing the jsp page at `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp` is all you need to do. This is where I found out it's not the case! The page contents are compiled within the `ROOT` web application servlet. To make Tomcat reference the jsp page instead, we need to prevent this servlet from being compiled.

Locate the ROOT web application’s config file at `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`, and simply comment out the following code fragment:

```
<!-- Comment this section so I can change the default index.jsp homepage
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
-->
```

This will disable the `index_jsp` servlet. Now when you restart the Tomcat web application server, it should compile and load the default `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp` page instead.