# Docker - A clean tomcat image

Tags: tomcat, docker

We are using the official tomcat dockerfile:
 https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

Problem is, the tomcat includes the MANAGER app (We really don't want or need).

Any ideas on how to remove it \ use a clean tomcat instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your own `Dockerfile` (which starts with FORM tomcat:x.y) in order to disable some part of it.

Take inspiration from "[How to disable Tomcat home page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8725257/6309)", by modifying `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp` (in the `Dockerfile`, `ADD` or `COPY` your own) for instance: apply that for the [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#Default_web_applications/Manager) though, not [ROOT](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#ROOT).

Or (recent Tomcat 9), [disallow (or allow only localhost) in the `manager.xml`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction)

The point remains: you can customize your Tomcat (following [the official Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html)) as an image before running it as a container.

Comment: How to customize docker tomcat image..After docker restart tomcat reset to fresh image state...

Comment: @Prasobh.K you need to write your own dockerfile, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870319/6309 for instance.